# Networking. Making a program available through the internet

Tags: networking

I want to create a program in which a user enters data and saves it on a text file. For example they enter a name and their age and it saves it and loads it. The thing is that i want this program to be available to the user at all times on any computer which means having the program online.

Do i need to make the program have networking capabilities? Or can i just have a server or host computer to hold the program and have the client access that directly?(like using the spreadsheets from google).

Comment: Why not just create a web application? Through java or javascript.

Comment: You have not accepted any answers, yet you have 8 questions with eligible answers.  Do not accept bad answers, but if you don't accept good answers you will find that people stop helping you.  Also, upvote all answers that are good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "do I need to make the program have networking capabilities". If you choose to avoid the web site route then you need to have a server and client side app. If you want the program to be able to save data to a server then you need to do some socket programming.

To create a server, you need to:

- create a socket
- bind the socket to an address and port
- listen for incoming connections
- wait for clients
- accept a client
- send and receive data

To create a client, you need to:

- create a socket
- connect to a server
- send and receive data

Hope this helps!

Comment: lets say i have a server or webpage, would this be enough to hold a program(like a spreadsheet)?

Answer (score 1):

There are may ways to accomplish your goal, but the route that is probably easiest and most useful is to create a web page that implements this functionality.

Some of the many benefits include

- No special software to install.  Just requires a web browser.
- Runs on any platform (including mobile) that has a web browser.
- No software updates to push out to users.  Update your website, and everyone gets the latest code.

Comment: if i were to use someone else's server would that be enough to run my program?

Comment: That depends on how large the server is, but if you're just updating a text file, it is very likely to work.